# Insert values into Access db from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-insert

I am getting an error when trying to insert values into an access database. The error says:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

All the value types are text in my Access db.

Here's my code:

Thanks.

```
Public Class NewUser
Dim cnn2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub NewUser_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cnn2 = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\UserInfo.accdb"
    frmMain.Visible = True
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn2.Open()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    If (txtPassword.Text = txtConfirm.Text) Then
        greenP.Visible = True
        Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn2.Open()
        End If

        cmd2.Connection = cnn2
        cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email, Username, Password) VALUES ('" & txtFirst.Text & "', '" & txtLast.Text & "', '" & txtAddress.Text & "', '" & txtCity.Text & "', '" & txtState.Text & "', '" & txtZip.Text & "', '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "')"

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn2.Close()

        txtAddress.Clear()
        txtCity.Clear()
        txtConfirm.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
        txtFirst.Clear()
        txtLast.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtState.Clear()
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtZip.Clear()
        txtFirst.Focus()
    Else
        redP.Visible = True
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match. Please enter again", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        txtConfirm.Clear()
        txtConfirm.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, [State], Zip, Email, Username, [Password]) VALUES ('" & txtFirst.Text & "', '" & txtLast.Text & "', '" & txtAddress.Text & "', '" & txtCity.Text & "', '" & txtState.Text & "', '" & txtZip.Text & "', '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "')"
```

Try this now, those MS Access keywords for tablenames are being encapsulated. [tablename] is equivalent to backticks on other RDBMS. It is used as an escaped keywords for table names.